# use IornPdf dll in python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7, python.net

I am trying to integrate IornPdf dll (https://ironpdf.com/) to python.
I'm using Python.Net (pip install pythonnet) to load the dll in python.

> I've kept the IronPdf.DLL  in (C:\Users<my-user>\Documents).

I have tried the following code in 64 bit version of python3.7  and 32 bit version of python3.9  ( same system).

Getting FileNotFoundException in both cases.

```
D:\>python
    Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    import clr
    import sys
    clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")    // Its working

    sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\<my-user>\Documents')
    clr.AddReference(r"C:\Users\<my-user>\Documents\IronPdf")
    clr.AddReference("C:\\Users\\<my-user>\Documents\\IronPdf")
    clr.AddReference("C:\\Users\\<my-user>\Documents\\IronPdf.DLL")
    clr.AddReference("IronPdf.DLL")
    clr.AddReference("IronPdf.dll")
    clr.AddReference("IronPdf")
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'IronPdf'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

---

```
 >> C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python
    Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:04:37) [MSC v.1929 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
 >> same error here too
```

---

I've created a sample dll, and AddReference working fine, But not able to use the class and functions defined in it.

```
using System;

namespace MathLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    { 
      ......
    }
}

D:> python
import clr
import sys
sys.path.append('path to the dll')
clr.AddReference("MathLibrary")
<System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly object at 0x000001C7B5BAE708>
from MathLibrary import Class1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MathLibrary
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe windows security services blocked the dll.. it did for me!

Windows was not enabling it to load from "external sources". To fix this i did:

1. Right-click on the .dll
2. "Properties"
3. Under "General", click "Unblock"

Also ensure the correct .Net runtimes are present on the host machine.

Comment: thank you for the support,  I couldn't find "Unblock" in Properties>general.

Comment: https://www.limilabs.com/blog/unblock-dll-file helped me on this

Comment: add AddReference issue solved(IornPdf), but cant import the  classes in the dll.

Comment: How to list the classes and methods of a added Reference